Block access to webform using a handler?
I have a webform that that uses some query parameters to set required fields. If the parameters are not provided, I want to block access to the webform.
I can currently get the handler to close the form, but it would be nicer to either:
a. Hide the form and show an error message, or
b. Redirect to an error page.
Here's the current code I have in my handler for this:
  public function prepareForm(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $operation, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // check if the eventid query parameter is set
    $event_id = $_GET['event1'];
    \Drupal::logger('event_registration_webform_handler')->notice('Event ID: ' . $event_id);
    if (!isset($event_id)) {
      // Load the webform
      $webform = $webform_submission->getWebform();
      // If the event id is not set, don't show the form
      $webform->setPropertyOverride('status', FALSE);
    }
  }

I thought that having a similar check in the access handler might work but it doesn't seem to fire. Any suggestions?
